# Apollo Client's evict from cache but never re-render

Tags: caching, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm using Apollo's Client and trying to evict the `address` object from the cache.
Using `evict` does remove it from the cache (confirmed by Apollo Client Dev Tools), however, it looks like the component does not rerender and the `address` would still be there unless I refresh the page.

```
              deleteAddress({
                variables: { id: data.address.id },
                update: (cache) => {
                  cache.evict({
                    id: "Address:" + data.address.id,
                  });
                  cache.gc();
                },
              })
            }
```

Specifically, I tried the following 2 methods, both removed the object from the cache but neither re-render.

```
                  cache.evict({
                    id: "Address:" + data.address.id,
                  });
                  cache.gc();
```

```
                 cache.evict({
                    id: cache.identify(data?.address),
                  });
```

Comment: Any fix for this? I am also facing same issue